# Namespace in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

I have two questions.

1. How to get namespace in asp.net
   website. like In asp.net web
   application we can see the namespace
   for every new added item. like that
   how can we have namespace in asp.net
   website for every item. I have to
   call the method of class which I
   placed in APP-code folder directly.
2. In my aspx.cs pageload method I
   have to declare public/private
   variables and I have to create the
   object of class what is the order.
   Which i need to declare first either
   declaring variables or creating
   obect of class.

My questions are basic but I am confused.

Please help me
Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion: post two different questions and include some sample code illustrating the problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are incomprehensible.
You may be looking for the [`<namespaces>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx) in Web.config.

Comment: He's refering to the code in the App_Code-folder. By default ASP.NET does not add a namespace for code-files generated in this folder.

Comment: Yes arjen your correct.How to add namespace for website and i should get namespace for every new item added to the website

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you tried: Right-Click the website in Solution Explorer, click Properties, adjust the default namespace on the Application Tab. Is this different to a website?

2) Declare public variables above the pageload event and set them within the pageload event.

Comment: Sorry did't see the Application tab. I'm working on vs2010.cloud u pls say any alternative

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to set a default namespace on website projects but it is simple to add it yourself after the new file has been created as per:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MySite
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1
    /// </summary>
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
    }
}
```

I don't fully understand your second question however if I'm understanding you correctly the order that you create an instance of a class or a variable doesn't matter. Create them as you need them. Variables / objects created in the pageload event will only be available in that event. If you need public variable declare it at the class level.